# Keeping a DB updated - Android

Tags: android, sql

With your help, I have successfully created a web page which has its own MySQL DB and then uses a JSON web service to pass the values my Android application.

The next stage is to copy them into a local SQLite DB so the phone does not require an internet connection to view the list.

I have successfully implemented code that creates a table, and inserts values into this table.
The problem is, I don't want it to necessarily re-write the whole DB at a time, which is the current idea to keep it current.

I might have things in the DB deleted or more things added, and want the local DB to reflect this.

What steps can I take to delete things that are no longer present in the MySQL DB in the SQLite one, and add new things?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have some sort of primary key in both databases? if so, why can't you just create a method in your webservice which returns an array of all the primary keys, and checks them against the SQLite database?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this should be to have a date time column in your database and then just fetch the posts that are newer then the last time you fetched from the database, in your android app you could save an date time in your preferences

I'm sorry I missed that you wanted to delete items as well, than this probably isn't the best approach. Are you using the mySQL only for the API? Then you could probably mark posts as deleted inserted odd feeling them.

Answer (score 0):

You can think this approach, parse your JSON response into objects of your data model and then create the content values holding that data model to work with the database in your device.

Once you have the content values, use a content resolver to work with your database and try an update of each data parsed from the JSON response (each content value), update method of the content resolver will return an integer value that tell us the number of rows updated in the database, if such number is 0 means that no data were in the database, so make an insertion, simply.

In that way you first search if the current data is present in the database, if it is, update it, if not, insert it.